# Error on starting HDFS daemons on hadoop Multinode cluster.Datanode not starting

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to setup hadoop cluster and getting following error while connecting datanode.Namenode is up and running fine,however datanode is creating problem.
/etc/hosts file is available on both the nodes.
IP tables stopped(f/w).
ssh happening.

> 2015-05-20 20:54:05,008 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying
>   connect to server: nn1.cluster1.com/192.168.1.11:9000. Already tried 9
>   time(s); retry policy is
>   RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1
>   SECONDS) 2015-05-20 20:54:05,017 ERROR
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: java.io.IOException:
>   Call to nn1.cluster1.com/192.168.1.11:9000 failed on local exception:
>   java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host

Comment: Could you `ping` to `192.168.1.11`?

Comment: Ping going to NN1.cluster1. Com I.e 192.168.1.11 however not able to ping dn1.cluster1. Com

Answer (score 1):

> java.io.IOException: Call to nn1.cluster1.com/192.168.1.11:9000 failed on local exception: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host

This error occurs if you have **firewall** on **namenode** system. To disable firewall, type these commands in terminal.

```
service iptables save
service iptables stop
chkconfig iptables off
```

Now, stop and start the hadoop processess.

Comment: @shasheer01 Please accept this as the answer, if your problem was fixed by this solution